# How can I determine if several sequences of sample-without-replacement are non-random?

Tags: probability, sampling

Suppose that, every day for 12 days, I visit a non-communicative giant and each day I bring a box of doughnuts. The number of doughnuts that I bring with me changes day-to-day (ranging from 9-27). There are 8 flavours to choose from (plain, chocolate, custard-filled, glazed, choc+custard, choc+glazed, custard+glazed, choc+custard+glazed). However, I do not bring an equal distribution of flavours and the distribution changes on each day. The giant must finish the entire box of doughnuts each day and I record the order of doughnut selection.

1. How can I determine if the giant is selecting doughnuts non-randomly?
2. If the selection is non-random, how can I rank-order preferences?
3. Can I determine if the selection becomes random at some point during the selection process (i.e. after the giant is sated or all the preferred types are gone)?

If I consider only 2 categories of flavours - those with chocolate and those without chocolate - then is a Mann-Whitney U on choice indices the correct test?

The real context is that I'm trying to determine if my brain-computer interface classifier prefers certain types of neural features when added greedily one-at-a-time to the model. I have 12 sessions of data to work with and the number of sorted neurons varies from session to session. I've classified these neurons into 8 classes based on some characteristics (A, B, C, A+B, A+C, B+C, A+B+C, none).